# Matrix indexing, extracting different columns for each row

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

Example with small arrays at the bottom.
I have a numpy array data of dimension MxN (N>100) and a smaller array A with dimensions Mx100.

Array A contains column indicies of the data array.

I want to extract all columns of data that are given by the indices in A.
The problem is that the indices in A are different for each row.

I tried

```
 data[:,A]
```

but this returns me a MxMx100 array.
I just want a Mx100 array.
I could do this in a for loop, but that takes very long.
How can I do this properly?

Example:

```
data=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]])
A=np.array([[0,1],[1,2],[0,2]])
```

I want to extract:
first row: index 0 and 1. second row: index 1 and 2. third row: index 0 and 2

Desired result:

```
array([[1,2],
[5,6],
[7,9]])
```

Comment: It would really help if you posted a small [mcve] with, say, `array1` with dimensions `MxN` and `A` with dimensions `Mx2` for some small `M` and `N`

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `broadcasting`

```
>>> data[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], A]

array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 9]])
```